# CSS and JavaScript elements strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I'm trying to build an Ajax menu using a style. It's interesting:

1. The Ajax is working (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytKc0QsVRY4)
2. The CSS is working (http://www.slicemaker.com/article_583.htm#.U2gXRMdzFq0

   [Download code](http://slicemaker.com/sample/download/article-css-navigation-2.zip)

But ... I don't know how to make them work together.

This is "index.php" (main page)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Green Navigation with jQuery Drop Down Menu Effect.</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
        <script src="js/general.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="day001"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="day002"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="day003"><span>Tab 3</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="day001"><span>Tab 1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="day002"><span>Tab 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="day003"><span>Tab 3</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content"></div>

        <a href="http://apycom.com/" style="display:none;"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is general.js:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        // Initial
        $('#content').load('content/day001.php');

        // Handle menu clicks
        $('div#menu ul li a').click(function()
        {
            var page = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php' );
            return false;
        });
    }
);
```

The interesting part is that this code creates two menus: One with Ajax and another with CSS.

How do I join the two?

Comment: I think your problem might be that you are loading the whole page (menu + content) into the `#content` element and not just the actual content and thus end up with 2 menus. `.load` can be used in a fashion like `$('#content').load(.content/page.php .some_selector')` where `.some_selector` stands for the element from the page you are loading via AJAX that you want to insert into `#content`.

Comment: thanks Christian... I'm ending up with two menus because I duplicated the DIV ... It's the behaviour that I can not understand... the same code behave differently in the two similar instances (while both behaviours are not complete - one is missing the css and another the js...After a long fight with the code I believe its not a css issue but somehow the two js files are overriding each other :( ... It's two complicated for me. so I'll search for another solution. Thanks for your help